# How to protect PC (ports) when connected camera may suffer vandalism?

Tags: usb, protection, short-circuit

### Background

I have a USB webcam installed above my door that acts like a video intercom for my countryside house, but I'm worried somebody may try to cut the wires, disable it and damage the computer it's connected to while doing so. My neighbors there have much more expensive systems installed and some of them were recently victims or such vandalism.

### The problem

I'd like to improve my current design so that the computer to which the webcam is connected wouldn't be damaged if the USB cable were to be tampered with.

The computer is a small cheap nettop (netbook) PC with 4 USB ports.

### The asks

1. What are the failure modes that could be applied to the exposed camera that could propagate to the attached PC and damage it too?
2. Are there devices that allow protection of USB ports from short-circuiting?
3. Should I switch to another type of inexpensive camera instead?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design. 

Comment: I believe that the more expensive looking the camera is, the more likely the house is to get burgled or vandalized along the way.

Comment: Embed the camera in the wall. Or put it in a box. HIDE it.

Comment: This question is on topic. It's just not entirely obvious as worded. The question really about short-circuit protection (and other forms of electrical protection) resulting from an exposed computer peripheral subject to physical damage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most USB ports are protected against short-circuit.

You could be extra sure your computer would survive by connecting the camera to a cheap USB *powered* hub (and connecting the hub to the computer).

To be even more sure, you should open the hub and physically disconnect pins 1, 4, and 5 (if present) of the USB connector that goes to the PC.

To be even more sure, you could install a fuse or PTC polyfuse in-line with the +5VDC power source.

Answer (score 5):

Wireless would prevent somebody from electrically damaging the host computer through the cable, but if you're dealing with vandals I would suggest a decoy/dummy camera in plain sight with the real one hidden.

Comment: Huh, this is actually a smart and low cost way to protect the pc.

Comment: and a 3rd camera watching both the other cameras!